# GPS Add-on GPIO Board Prevents Pi From Booting

Tags: gpio, boot-issues, gps, freebsd

I'm using the following set up to build an NTP Server:

- Raspberry Pi B+
- Raspberry PI [GPS Add-on](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/raspberry-pi-gps-add-on.html)
- FreeBSD 10.1 built with CrochetBSD

I am able to boot my Pi without the GPS Add-on.  When I plug in the GPS Add-on into the GPIO connector, my Pi fails to boot before starting the kernel.

It shows up to the point where it says "Press enter to prevent auto boot" and then the letter 'L' shows up and starts erasing text from the screen.

Why would plugging in the GPS Add-on cause this and how do I begin to trouble shoot the boot sequence?

Comment: What size power supply are you using?

Comment: The NEO-6 uses as quoted on another site `111 mW @ 3.0V (continuous)` But what is the 5v supply required for on this PCB? The specs on the link provided are very skimpy.

Comment: @goldilocks I'm using the block that came with my HTC One M8.  It's output specs are 5V 1.5A.

Comment: @ppumkin I'm not sure what you're asking.  The board itself doesn't have any inputs for power aside from the GPIO connector.

Comment: Yea, the GPIO 5v is DIRECTLY connected to the USB power. the 3v3 goes through voltage regulator that comes from 5v0. Try and use a 2amp power supply and see if it continues. I am just saying the link you provided said it used 5v and 3v3 for GPIO, but the actual GPS runs at 3v0 ... but its unclear

Comment: I will see if I have a 2A power supply lying around.  Thanks for the information, but I'm sorry to say it goes over my head.  Would it be possible to explain it a bit simpler?  I'm don't get electricity very well.

Comment: Have you tried booting with Raspbian instead of FreeBSD?

Comment: @Craig I haven't tried using Raspbian.  I'll have to give it a shot later tonight when I get home.

Comment: @ppumkin I just tried a 2.1A power supply and it did not work.

Comment: @Craig I get a similar issue with Raspbian.  It gets through loading the kernel and when the screen to start Raspbian Software Configuration I get the following:

`SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystem(j) sak(k) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) show-blocked-test(w)`

It just repeatedly displays that message.  If I choose any of the options it shows the results & continues printing the messages above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the GPS module is interacting with the serial console.

Try disabling the serial console:

- Remove **console=ttyAMA0,115200** from `/boot/cmdline.txt`
- Comment out the line **T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100** in `/etc/inittab`

Comment: This is what the FreeBSD Embedded emailing list said as well. I disabled the serial console in Raspbian and I was able to boot. I will confirm that this was the case for FreeBSD as well as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't see either of those files...

Comment: Those are on Raspbian. On FreeBSD `/etc/ttys` is used instead of `/etc/inittab`. I don't know the equivalent of `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Comment: Thanks man!  I'll give that a shot later.  And when I figure out the proper steps to boot FreeBSD with the GPS chip attached I'll do a small write up.